# How do I get a js-created token using Watir?

Tags: ruby, macos, watir, watir-webdriver

Installed `watir-webdriver` in the attempt to submit a form like this:

https://gist.github.com/f46e8a0ed433fdb16371587920ee4b64

Was thinking I could do this:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'URL'

return b.execute_script(validateLoginForm())
```

Not working.

Comment: Is the value then getting stored as a cookie or a local/session storage? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

This could be as easy as:

```
return b.execute_script("return validateLoginForm()")
```

Comment: Well, I followed [this](https://mayxu.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/complete-mac-setup-guide-for-rubycucumberwatirselenium-12/) to install on Mac, and when I run your line firefox quits unexpectedly, and when I cancel the command in terminal I get [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8bd673a1d532f620dd850478d359e632).

Comment: To collect javascript errors, you'll either need to use a proxy or have access to the source code of the page you are testing to add custom javascript. Check out jimevans description of one way to make it work: http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/09/capturing-javascript-errors-in.html